# PLM solution for research work

Tags: cad, oracle-agile-plm

I am looking for a free PLM (Product Lifecycle Managment) solution to test some scientific work. I was looking in sourceforge.net but i cannot find any feedback. So, any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Aras PLM](http://www.aras.com/support/). It's "freely available for download and use at no charge"

Comment: Just an FYI, It is "Free" to download and use, but you cannot use any of the connection functions without a subscription..